# HtmlWeb.LoadAsync cannot resolve symbol

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use `HtmlAgilityPack`, namely a `HtmlWeb.LoadAsync` method which is commonly mentioned in internet. But it cannot be resolved by Visual Studio. `HtmlWeb` class is resolved, but `LoadAsync` method is not. My project is WPF 4.5 Windows desktop application. I have loaded HtmlAgilityPack Nuget package, HtmlAgilityPack library is in references (version 1.4.6.0) and `using HtmlAgilityPack;` is in code too, but it still cannot resolve. What could be the problem?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `LoadAsync()` only available on `HtmlAgilityPack` version for platforms where synchronous download is not supported by default eg. HAP for Metro apps, Silverlight, Windows Phone, etc.

For WPF application, use synchronous `Load()` method. And if you need it to load `HtmlDocument` asynchronously, you could manually run `Load()` method in different, non-UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

I would download the HTML text asynchronously and then process it.
Something like this:

```
var htmlDoc = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlDoc );
```